# How to take inputs argument separated by commas in C command line?

Tags: c, command-line

(C Program) I need help on an assignment where I must take an input from the command line in the format `cmd1,cmd2,cmd3,cmd4`, where each command is separated by a comma. How can I accomplish this? Is there a way where I can the entire line as a string and then parse it?

To explain further, the user executes the program like this after compiling:

```
./a.out cmd1,cmd2,cmd3,…,cmdN
```

The number of commands not limited.
If there is a way to take the argument as a single string that would be best, as I can just parse the commands in the program.

I don't need help parsing the text; just some direction on how to get the command line argument.

Comment: `I don't need help parsing the text, just some direction on how to get the cmd line argument.` Its in `argv`, usually.

Comment: `int main(int argc, char **argv) { if (argc != 2) err_usage("%s cmd1,cmd2,…,cmd3", argv[0]); …parse argv[1]… }`.

Comment: @wes sheck Just out of curiorsity: Why don't you use ``` ```(space) to seperate the commands? In that way you can use ```argc``` to get the number of commands and use ```argv``` to access them.

Comment: @JiaHaoXu: I think the reason is "an assignment … must take … format `cmd1,cmd2,cmd3,cmd4`" — in other words, the teacher is trying to teach how to do this unorthodox usage for whatever reason, rather than because wes sheck thinks it's a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

When you run a `c` program, the `main` function gets 2 parameters:

```
 main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

where the first one is the number of the command line arguments, the second is the array which contains the arguments.

command line arguments are split by spaces and parts of the string constitute the `argv` array.

In your case 'cmd1,cmd2,cmd3' does not seem to contain any space, so these will be a single element in the `argv` array. As soon as you add spaces, you will get more args. i.e. `cmd1 , cmd2` will end up in 3 args: `cmd1`, `,` and `cmd2`.

I guess your task would be to merge all args into a single string and then parse this string, tokenizing it by the `,` delimiter.

Note that argv[0] will contain the path of the program you run.